# jquery tabs to open the tab with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I've been having a problem that took more time than it should.
I am using jquery.tabs.js, there is a tab container that contains months and inside each month there is a ul list containing items.
The page is called "Past Items" so when the user opens this page today let's say, yesterday's item will have a class "selected-item" and it will be highlighted, and the container month or tab will have a class "selectedmonth", the question is how can I make this tab opens once the page is accessed? The 1st tab opens by default.
check: [past items](http://www.theoikos.com/clients/breedo/beta/past-items.php)

and click on May.
I hope I could explain what I need :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the "selected" option

```
$("#your_tabs").tabs({ 
    [ ... your options ... ]
    selected: X
});
```

With X being the zero-based index of the tab to open (in your exemple X needs to be 4).

To select the tab after initialization, you can use the select() method

```
$("#your_tabs").tabs("select", X);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply it helped me, and sorry for the delay to respond :) I'm new to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a little JQuery+CSS Hack.

1- Remove tabs-selected class from every tab

```
$(".monthscontainer li").removeClass("tabs-selected");
```

2- Add a tabs-selected class  to the current month , it shows the fifth month will be highlighted:

```
$(".monthscontainer  li:nth-child(5)").addClass("tabs-selected");
```

or

```
$(".selectedmonth").addClass("tabs-selected");
```

3- add tabs-hide class to the first tabdiv

```
$(".tabs-container:first").addClass("tabs-hide");
```

4- remove tabs-hide on the fifth div.

```
$("#2011-5").removeClass("tabs-hide");
```

Yes , I know it is a  hack, but it seems  Jquery UI tab doesn't contain the different selection as default instead of first tab.

I am sorry, lepidosteus is right, the easiest way if you put the selection in the load function:

```
$( ".months" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 5 );
```

[You can read more here about this](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs)

Comment: Thank you also for your help, and sorry for the delay to respond :) I'm new to Stackoverflow.